# Why does my Groovy script run in the Jenkins Script Console but not as a Groovy Postbuild Script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

This script runs in the my Jenkins Script Console but not as Groovy Postbuild script.

```
job = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem("MyJob")
build = job.getLastBuild()
action = build.getAction(jenkins.metrics.impl.TimeInQueueAction.class)
```

- Jenkins ver. 1.625.3
- Groovy Postbuild plugin v 2.0

It fails on the last line. I have the Metrics Plugin installed v 3.0.11 which ***should*** give me access to the metrics library.

It seems like I have to somehow import the TimeInQueueAction class int the plugin, even the Script Console can access it.

Can you help?

EDIT: the error I get:

```
5:03:40 groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jenkins for class: Script1
15:03:40    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
15:03:40    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
15:03:40    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
15:03:40    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:3)
15:03:40    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:580)
15:03:40    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:618)
15:03:40    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:589)
15:03:40    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:166)
15:03:40    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildRecorder.perform(GroovyPostbuildRecorder.java:355)
15:03:40    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
15:03:40    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
15:03:40    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:726)
15:03:40    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
15:03:40    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:671)
15:03:40    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
15:03:40    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
15:03:40    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
15:03:40    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
15:03:41 Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Are you running it as a system groovy script?

Comment: I'm not using the Groovy plugin, it's the Groovy Postbuild plugin. I'm using this because it's post-build so that I can collect stats after the build has completed. AFAIK the Groovy plugin runs scripts as system scripts, guessing the Groovy Postbuild plugin doesn't?

Comment: They might have different classpath. Try taking a look for a global configuration of Groovy Postbuild, there might be some sandboxing settings (I don't mean Pipeline sandboxes). Otherwise you can try another approach: install Conditional BuildStep Plugin + AnyBuildStep plugin, then configure AnyBuildStep to allow all steps. After that you should be able in a PostBuild section to add a Conditional Build Step, and use System Groovy script step from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that upgrading the plugin from 2.0 to 2.3.1 did the trick.